# Datagrid is not filtering

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a datagrid that gets filled out with table data with a loadStudentTable() method.

I have search box in which i am trying to filter the dataGrid with values that contain.

It doesnt seem to be working. States the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

***Search Text Change***

```
private void SearchTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try 
            { 
                (studentGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Student_FName LIKE '%{0}%'", SearchTxt.Text);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

***Student table load***

```
 //Fills out Student table
    private void loadStudentTable()
    {
        SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
        conn2.Open();

        try
            {
                SqlCommand cmdDatabase2 = new SqlCommand("Select * from Student", conn2);
                SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sda2.SelectCommand = cmdDatabase2;
                DataTable dbdataset2 = new DataTable();
                sda2.Fill(dbdataset2);
                BindingSource bSource2 = new BindingSource();

                bSource2.DataSource = dbdataset2;
                studentGridView.DataSource = bSource2;
                sda2.Update(dbdataset2);

                studentGridView.Columns[0].Width = 92;
                studentGridView.Columns[1].Width = 200;
                studentGridView.Columns[2].Width = 180;
                studentGridView.Columns[3].Width = 180;
                studentGridView.Columns[4].Width = 170;
                studentGridView.Columns[5].Width = 170;
                studentGridView.Columns[6].Width = 130;                        
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        conn2.Close();
    }
```

Loading the table is fine, its just the filtering to what input is used in the search text box.

Any ideas or help please.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid`!! This is wrong and confusing.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type..

Comment: @TaW Sorry, i will next time. Feel free to edit it or ask me to edit and i will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your code as below and try..

```
private void SearchTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try 
        { 

        var bindData = (BindingSource)studentGridView.DataSource;
        var dataTable = (DataTable)bindData.DataSource;
        dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format(""Student_FName LIKE '%{0}%'", SearchTxt.Text);    
        studentGridView.Refresh();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a quick question, what if i want to use the same query for finding Student_Username or Student_SName. Where would i change and what should i add? as i want to minimise code reuse

Comment: Hi @DB, In the above code you are searching on **Student_FName** column and if you would like to perform search based on another column just change the column name like following string.Format(""Student_Username LIKE '%{0}%'", SearchTxt.Text). And, if you indent to code reuse create a common class and make a global datatable object.